# Перенос приложения с базой данных

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Собственно есть приложение в Apex Oracle, с подключенной бд, сделанноe тоже в ней.

Как это можно перенести на другой ПК ? Приложение с базой данных.

Answer (score 1):

Приложение можно перенести встроенным в апекс импортом/экспортом (большая кнопка "Import" на странице приложения).

Саму БД просто так перенести не получится - придется переносить, например, с помощью утилит `expdp`/`impdp`. Если есть скрипт создания БД и заполнения её данными, то можно выполнить его на другом ПК через интерфейс апекса (раздел "SQL Workshop" - "SQL Scripts").

Ну и настройку воркспейса нужно сделать на новом ПК, если она еще не сделана.